# How to show previous value based on selection from quick filter in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I like to show the previous period value with difference based on the period selected from the quick filter in Tableau.

For example:

If I select 2019 from quick filter I would like to see the value with the difference compared with previous period (i.e 2018) 
(means 2019 (from quick filter) vs 2018).

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a quick filter value directly in tableau instead use parameters where you can access the parameters in calculated fields.

For this requirement LoD serves the purpose, where use a `Fixed LoD` which will bypass the filtering and get you the values.

For E.g

```
{Fixed :Sum(if year = 2018 then sales end)}
```

In worksheet you have 2019 value then use a calculated field to find the difference

Edit-------------------------------------

If quick filter is a single value selection then you can subtract 1 from year field. like below:

```
{Fixed :Sum(if year = [datbasefield.year]-1 then sales end)}
```

Comment: This is fine, but in my requirement we don't know which value user will select so based on the user selection previous period value should show

Comment: @Kumar is the user selection through filter is a single or multi value selection?

Comment: single value selection

Comment: @Kumar check my edit and if answer works, accept it as asnwered and close the thread

Comment: what "year" means after "if" is it a calculated field??

Comment: @Kumar year component of date database field?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a filter to select your period, use a parameter. Then you can use a calculated field to filter to both the year selected by the parameter and the prior year.

If you then want to calculate the difference between two years, you can use a Quick Table Calc (right click on the green measure pill on whatever shelf you are using).

If you then want to hide that first (empty) value, use the hide command or a table calc filter.

So in a nutshell, read about parameters and table calculations in the on-line help

Comment: Thanks for the help here, I have different requirement as below: I have requirement where I have current year 4 quarters (Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4) as a quick filters in my dashboard. so when 

selecting Q1 it should show difference when comparing with 2018 Q4, when selecting Q2 it should show difference 

when comparing with Q1 of this year only (i.e QoQ difference) like that Q3 vs Q3 (difference) and Q4 vs Q3 

difference. In my view/sheet I want to show only selected quarter value as well as show difference when comparing 

with previous period (in this case quarters - Q1/Q2/Q3/Q4).

Comment: As best as I can understand your comment, I think the approach (briefly) outlined in my answer still applies. Don't filter to just one quarter (otherwise the prior quarter is not available for comparison). Instead, use a parameter to allow the user to choose their quarter of interest. Then use a table calculation to compute the QoQ difference. Finally you can use the Hide command to not display the prior values and a boolean calculated field to filter out quarters not needed by the calculations.